# Percentage change calculation - mutate and lead functions giving NA values in new column

Tags: r, na, percentage, lead, mutate

I am trying to calculate percentage change between elements in a vector of a dataframe:

Year

| Year | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2010 | 55302 |
| 2011 | 58943 |
| 2012 | 59633 |
| 2013 | 50194 |

But I the new column I create is only giving NA values instead of the percentage change calculation I want between the count of each year:

| Year | Count | Pct_change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 55302 | NA |
| 2011 | 58943 | NA |
| 2012 | 59633 | NA |
| 2013 | 50194 | NA |

My code is as follows:

```
df1    <- df %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  mutate(Pct_change = (Count - lead(Count) / lead(Count)*100)
```

I thought it may be the fact the Count column is integer values so I changed it to numeric, no success. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Just remove the `group_by(Year)` and it should work i.e. `df %>%  mutate(Pct_change = (Count - lead(Count) / lead(Count)*100)`.  There is only a single observation per 'Year'

Comment: Just tried but it hasn't unfortunately, still getting NA values down the whole column

Comment: This is what I get from your data `df %>% mutate(Pct_change = (Count - lead(Count) / lead(Count)*100)) %>% pull(Pct_change)#
[1] 55202 58843 59533    NA`

Comment: Perhaps you have non-numeric column.  Change it to numeric and do the calcuation

Comment: Maybe you miss some `(` like this: `df %>% mutate(Pct_change = ((Count - lead(Count)) / lead(Count)*100))
`

Comment: Changed all columns to numeric but still getting the same result

Comment: I have changed the brackets around and still the same result..feel like I've tried everything at this point

Comment: @akrun is my syntax wrong then? Weird that you're getting numbers as I'm still getting NA

Comment: Please check whether your column is `character` class.

Comment: @akrun all columns are numeric

Comment: Then, I am not sure.  Perhaps use `dplyr::lead` instead of just lead (in case you have some packages loaded with same function

Comment: @akrun still no good, the dataframe that is piping into mutate was collapsed and duplicate years and counts were removed ... would that have anything to do with it?

Comment: You may have to show the `dput(yourexample)` to understand the correct structure

Comment: @akrun 

> dput(atm_per_year)
structure(list(Year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2018, 2019), Count = c(55302, 58943, 59633, 50194, 
49276, 58619, 54073, 52968, 55243, 58765)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), vars = "Year", drop = TRUE, indices = list(0L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
    Year = 2010:2019), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), vars = "Year", drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: I get error `! Corrupt `grouped_df` using old (< 0.8.0) format.`.  You may `ungroup` the data and test

Comment: i.e. `atm_per_year %>% ungroup %>% mutate(Pct_change = (Count - lead(Count) / lead(Count)*100))`

Comment: @akrun Still no good, looks like I might have to calculate manually :(

Comment: I was able to get the output with `ungroup`ing your data because the `grouped_df` in the class is giving me corrupt data, so i removed that class.  IN your dataset, I would assume `ungroup` to work or just convert to `data.frame` and then apply ie.. `atm_per_year %>% as.data.frame %>% mutate(Pct_change = (Count - lead(Count) / lead(Count)*100))`

Comment: forget that last comment, it's worked!! Thanks @akrun you're a life safer

Answer (score 0):

The dataset had some groupings as the class had `grouped_df`.  We could `ungroup` before applying the code

```
library(dplyr)
atm_per_year %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   mutate(Pct_change = (Count - lead(Count) / lead(Count)*100))
```